# What size RPBP/RPZ should I use for a 3/4" city water meter?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, landscaping, irrigation

A friend has a 3/4" (0.75") water meter at their 1.3 ac property. We want to do some fertigation with their irrigation so we're looking at a Reduced Pressure Backflow Preventer. The main line for the irrigation and hose bibs is going to be 1.5" PVC.

What size RPBP/RPZ should we use?

I was thinking that since I'm using the 1.5" mainline that we'd need a 1.5" RPBP/RPZ, but I feel like that's overkill given the 3/4" meter.

Thanks for any guidance on this. I don't want to get a mega overkill system going, but do want it to not be overly throttled and lead to irrigation issues down the line. Thanks!